# Combine the two interface with/without argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have two template class, I think there's a way to combine into one with std::enable_if but not 100% sure, anybody knows?

```
template <typename ReturnType>
class NoArgBase {
  std::function<ReturnType(void)> func_;

 public:
  explicit NoArgBase(std::function<ReturnType(void)> func)
      : func_{std::move(func)} {}
  ReturnType operator()() const {
    return func_();
  }
};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class ArgBase {
  std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func_;

 public:
  explicit ArgBase(std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
      : func_{std::move(func)} {}
  ReturnType operator()(Args... args) const {
    return func_(args...);
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? The second one looks like it can do everything the first one can.

Comment: Oh right :) BTW, I think it should be  "const Args...&&" instead of "Args..." as well, yeah, in deed we don't need the first one at all :)

Comment: *"it should be "const Args...&&" instead of "Args...""* I don't think so, `Args...` is ok. You do need to `std::forward` `args` though, see how [`std::function::operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()) is implemented.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what's the downside if I don't "std::forward" it?

Comment: I guess it's totally fine to do this without std::forward? I see cases doing this. Is it not efficient if the args are rvalue reference?

Comment: If `Args` contains an rvalue reference, your code will fail to compile. If `Args` contains a non-reference, your code will make a copy instead of moving the argument.